# when try to add confirm mail function group get error Expected 1-2 arguments but got 3. ts(2554)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular-resource

Problem

error Expected 1-2 arguments but got 3. ts(2554) when add confirm email as third argument ?

I work on angular 7 I make register users form

when do validation compare user mail to confirm mail  on Reactive form .

function group not accept to add argument for mail confirm as code below

so How to add confirm email on register form ?

```js
import {MustMatchEmail} from '../helpers/EmailValidator';
import {MustMatch} from '../helpers/must-match.validator';
constructor() {}
UserMail = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$'), Validators.maxLength(100)]);

ConfirmedEmail = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(100)])

ngOnInit() {
  this.createFormValidations();
}
createFormValidations() {
  this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      UserMail: this.UserMail,
      ConfirmedEmail: this.ConfirmedEmail,
      UserPass: this.UserPass,
      ConfirmedPassword: this.ConfirmedPassword,

    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('UserPass', 'ConfirmedPassword')
    },
    //here error function not accept mail confirm
    {
      validator: MustMatchEmail('UserMail', 'ConfirmedEmail')
    }
  );
}
```

[image: cannot add confirm email on function group]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Reference: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userMail: [this.userMail, MustMatchEmail('UserMail','ConfirmedMail')],
});
```